# Map some of table fields into a dictionary

Tags: .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, bltoolkit

We have a legacy system which has the ability to add custom fields to its entites. This feature is implemented badly, to be exact: each entity table is extended with fields `Custom1`, ... `Custom 10`, and moreover, there's big table `CustomFields` (`EntityType`, `EntityID`, `Custom11`, ... `Custom99`), where `EntityType` is entity table's name.

We are building new code on top of the existing bad database and are searching for the possibilities to put all these Customs into a single dictionary when materializing. The ORMs we consider currently are *BLToolkit* and *EF4* (the former is in use now, we are planning to move to the latter).

Is there a possibility to implement this kind of mapping with either of two? Maybe some other ORM (probably, we'd like *heavy* ORM) might help? Or, there's a best practice of another kind?

Comment: So when `CustomFields` is used it is an EAV design?

Comment: @GertArnold: no, there's a flat structure both in main table and CustomFields.

Comment: You need a CRUD or only Read ?

Comment: @Memoizer: we need CRUD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit of investigation and discussions we've decided to introduce XML field in the entity table that contains the values of all custom fields. The field value is synchronized with actual custom field values in both directions.